# Is there a safe way to upgrade the laravel version in Production

Tags: laravel, version, laravel-upgrade

I have a Laravel 5.4 project (web application), it's a huge product. I want to add some well known packages like error logging and debugging. Is there any simple way to update the Laravel from 5.4 to 5.5 or 5.6 without affecting the things what was already done? How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should never upgrade your production environment directly without testing. It would be better to set up a staging environment and test the upgrade there. If you don't have any problems there, consider upgrading the production environment.

If you want to know all changes from older versions to newer versions, check the upgrade guides in order:

- https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/upgrade
- https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/upgrade
- https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/upgrade

Comment: Thanks for your comment yes i have a staging environment. i will test on staging first.